Проверка наличия локального файла в js
Друзья, буду признателен за помощь в решении следующей проблемы:
Есть набор файлов (картинок) в определенной директории на локальном ПК и есть ХТМЛ-файл в который эти картинки нужно подгрузить. Все картинки названы по определенному шаблону, например, scene-1, scene-2 и тд.
Я делал простенький скрипт, который подгружает нужную картинку по нажатию кнопки, по факту увеличивая лишь число в названии файла, но тут стала проблема, как остановить выполнение программы, если картинки закончились. Их может быть любое количество от полного отсутствия до нескольких тысяч, поэтому заранее прописать их все в коде в виде некоего массива невозможно.
Я нашел решение вроде вот такого:
  image.onerror = function(){
    num = 0;
    image.src = `./image/locations/scene-${num}.jpg`};

Но вариант с выпадающими в консоль ошибками как-то сильно напрягает. И вот мне интересно, а можно ли это переделать как-то в виде условия или калбек функции? Или может можно сделать некоторую предварительную проверку наличия файла перед выполнением остального скрипта?
let num = 0;

function next_step() {
  num++;
  let div_img = document.getElementById('image_block');
  let image = document.createElement('img');

  image.src = `./image/locations/scene-${num}.jpg`;
  image.className = 'image';
  image.onerror = function(){
    num = 0;
    image.src = `./image/locations/scene-${num}.jpg`};
  div_img.innerHTML = '';
  div_img.appendChild(image);
}
}

Собственно выше приведен все существующий на данный момент код.

Во-первых если количество фото может быть "до нескольких тысяч", то загружать их на клиент будет совершенно неправильно и пользователи просто расстреляют вас.. Во-вторых надо понимать зачем вся эта штука понадобилась, чтобы подсказать более правильное решение, а не то, как именно вы считаете правильно. В-третьих - почему бы подсчёт количества картинок  и отдачей в нужном количестве не дать на откуп серверу и языку на нём? Который может как просто посчитать количество картинок в папке, так и отдать нужное количество (или хотя бы сказать какие номера ещё доступны)

@Алексей Шиманский, на первое, второе и третье ответ очень прост - сервера НЕТ. Задача стоит в том, чтобы сделать самодостаточный локальный хтмл-проект, который будет полностью храниться на стороне пользователя и не будет никак привязан и ограничен наличием интеренета, сети или сервера. По факту, это десктопное приложение с браузером в качестве графической оболочки. Поэтому всякие клиент-серверные решения, вроде использования Node.js здесь не годятся, а вот наличие доступа к локальным файлам очень необходимо для корректного отображения данных.

Тогда я бы лично рекомендовал воспользоваться другим языком или ПО. Например C#, Java и пр, чтобы была какая-то "оконная программа" (как раз десктопная), которую пользователь мог просто в виде одной программы запустить. Иначе это в итоге обернётся в неимоверное костыляние (которое ужЕ началось)

@Алексей Шиманский, задача поставлена: сделать этот код на js, так что другие среды разработки не годятся. Да и где вообще ваш исследовательский интерес? Как же "Если решения нет, то мы его создадим с нуля"? Вы же, вроде как, творцы, для которых нерешаемых проблем просто не должно существовать. Представьте, что никаких других языков, кроме js просто не существует, а задачу решить нужно.

Это неправильный подход. Правильный подход - нужно подбирать инструменты под задачу. Иначе можно резать батон топором,  ехать через горную местность на спорткаре, а детей пытаться зачать безымянным пальцем руки (представьте, что нет полового органа, а задачу решить нужно....)

Мне понравился вот этот комментарий  который точно описывает проблематику. Когда ТС тоже хотел делать веб приложение на C и хаял всё остальное, ведь С - это очень быстрый язык и мощный, так почему бы не писать на нём.... Вот у вас примерно такое же.... Вы пытаетесь впихнуть невпихуемое

"задача поставлена"  --- вот 2024, вам в пекарне ставят задачу: запечь 500 пирожков, но используя при этом только тепло своих рук, кладя пирожок в ладонь одной руки и накрывая ладонью другой, запекать до румяной корочки.... Вы будете упорно пытаться выполнить поставленную задачу или, всё же, скажете, что есть более удобные и правильные инструменты для достижения этой цели?

@Алексей Шиманский, пример совершенно неудачен, ибо в случае с пирожками есть вполне реальные законы физики, которые никак обойти нельзя, а программирование ограничено исключительно нашей фантазией и вычислительными мощностями железа, на котором мы пытаемся что-то реализовать... Ладно, это все демагогия не по теме пошла... Скажем так, Ваше мнение я услышал, но меня оно не убедило.

@drako black а о каких выпадающих в консоль ошибках идет речь? Там ничего не должно быть, вроде.

@hlearn, в какой-то момент генерируется ссылка на файл, которого не существует и, естественно, система ругается на то, что файла нет. Скрин к посту сейчас добавлю.

@drakoblack то есть хотите сказать, что вы на brainfuck'е если сильно захотите, сможете микропроцессор сделать? Ну-ну

@Алексей Шиманский, создать микропроцессор на любом языке программирования невозможно, так как процессор - это материальный обьект, а языки программирования - это лишь интерпритаторы, которые помогают человеку понимать двоичный код машин. По факту, если бы мы могли легко понимать бинарный код, то никакие языки программирования нам в принципе не нужны были бы. Если же речь идет о каком-то виртуальном процессоре, то я думаю, что это вполне реально, вопрос лишь в том, сколько трудозатрат на это потребуется. Но это уже вопрос оптимизации, а не решения проблемы как таковой.

Браузер не даст вам сканировать директорию пользователя на предмет наличия там файла. В теории, если покопаться в настройках безопасности браузера, то можно разрешить кучу всего, но вот не уверен, что можно выдать полный доступ до файловой структуры. Касаемо вопроса, можно в цикле с 1 до бесконечности бежать по файлам и как только первый не найден(не загружен) останавливать перебор, но это будет проблемой, если у вас в картинках есть пропуски в нумерации. подавить ошибки можно в конструкции try catch.

@SwaD, вот об этом я и спрашивал, как условием задать проверку наличия файла по указанной ссылке без вызова ошибки? Пробелов в перечислении изображений не предполагается, порядок должен быть строго соблюден. Вариант  try catch сейчас погуглю, спасибо за возможную подсказку.

@SwaD, и можно пример проверки try catch на наличие файла? А то, что-то я не совсем понял, как задать проверку?

@drako black Так ошибки нет же. Вы обещали скриншот с ней. Пока не ясно, как она появляется, не ясен и способ применения try catch.

Можно попробовать The File System Access API

Можно попробовать File System API
Метод Window: showDirectoryPicker() позволяет выбрать директорию и получить список файлов, например так:
const directory = await window.showDirectoryPicker({mode: 'read'}); // открываем папку на чтение, получаем разрешение
for await (var [fileName, handler] of directory.entries()){ // проверяем файлы в папке
    console.log(fileName, handler.kind) 
}

В связи с ограничениями безопасности, данный код нужно поместить в обработчик нажатий кнопки. В процессе выполнения будет окно выбора папки, выбрав в котором папку в консоль выведется список файлов

Отвечаю тут. fetch не работает для file://.... Весь ответ - руины.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, а, с этой стороны да

@Grundy, действительно не работает... Но спасибо за попытку помочь в решении проблемы.

@drakoblack, в chrome работает. Можешь добавить в вопрос как именно и что конкретно ты пробовал

@Grundy, оу, возможно, что я не совсем правильно понял Ваш ответ. Уточните, пожалуйста, "обработчик событий" - это подразумевается "функция, которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку"? Если да, то я добавил Ваш код в эту функцию для исполнения и браузер "сошел с ума" в консоли. Если нет, то я не правильно понял, где именно нужно применить Ваш код и был бы признателен за разьяснения.

@drakoblack, пока ты не покажешь код, который у тебя в итоге получился и что значит браузер "сошел с ума" в консоли - нельзя сказать что именно ты делал не так. Приведенный код работает, если вызвать его непосредственно в консоли руками и при помещении в обработчик кнопки - если нужно из кода.

@Grundy, добавил код и хтмл разметку в свой вопрос. В таком вот виде это не работает. Видимо я что-то делаю не так.

@drakoblack, да, ты не поставил async перед function: async function next_step() { - о чем тебе и написано в консоли браузера

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
